# How to handle apostrophe in an INSERT statement when inserting into Clickhouse using Python?

Tags: python, clickhouse, apostrophe

I am inserting into Clickhouse but an error occurs because of the apostrophe in the statement.

```
tmp_list = ['A\'BCD','12345','1a2a3a4a']

insert = f'INSERT INTO tmp_table (NAME) VALUES (\'{tmp_list[0]}\', \'{tmp_list[1]}\', \'{tmp_list[2]}\')'
client.execute(insert)
```

**Output**

> ServerException: Code: 47.
> DB::Exception: Missing columns: 'A'BCD' while processing query: '`A'BCD`', required columns: 'A'BCD' 'A'BCD' : While executing ValuesBlockInputFormat.

```
tmp_list = ['A\'BCD','12345','1a2a3a4a']

insert = f'INSERT INTO tmp_table (NAME) VALUES ({repr(tmp_list[0])}, {repr(tmp_list[1])},{repr(tmp_list[2])})'
client.execute(insert)
```

**Output**

> ServerException: Code: 47.
> DB::Exception: Missing columns: 'A'BCD' while processing query: '`A'BCD`', required columns: 'A'BCD' 'A'BCD' : While executing ValuesBlockInputFormat.

Comment: This is terrible practice and you need to stop it now. This is how SQL Injection happens

Comment: It will, however, take me time to understand how to parameterize things for `clickhouse` because I'm not familiar with it